# how to find and update partial text in the SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some challenging column update in SQL. I need to update partial text in the column

```
 ID  DESCRIPTION
  1  Life Membership 10-Sep-2018 to 31-Dec-2018
  2  Oklahoma City Section 10-Sep-2018 to 31-Dec-2018
```

Need to update

```
 ID  DESCRIPTION
  1  Life Membership 01-Jan-2019 to 31-Dec-2019
  2  Oklahoma City Section 01-Jan-2019 to 31-Dec-2019
```

`Membership` or `section` always there then duration of the date. Please help me how to update this.

Comment: The problem here, really, is your design. This should be 3 different columns `Description`, `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks every row of column "description" for '10-Sep-2018' and replaces it to '01-Jan-2019'

update yourtable set description=replace(description,'10-Sep-2018','01-Jan-2019')

Note that as Larnu mentions, this is an incredibly bad design. This query will also change the *second* date too if it is '10-Sep-2018'

Comment: The dates are not static text. those date will change

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your full dataset, but it sounds like you want to crop out and paste in.  Here, I used CharIndex() to find the words 'Membership' and 'Section', then SubString to manipulate the strings based on the location of those words: (You can also use this logic to create a table where these values are in separate columns to improve your versatility)

```
Create Table #tbl
(
v VarChar(50)
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
('Life Membership 10-Sep-2018 to 31-Dec-2018'),
('Oklahoma City Section 10-Sep-2018 to 31-Dec-2018')
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
   Case 
      When CHARINDEX('Membership', v) > 0 Then 
           Substring(v,1,CHARINDEX('Membership',v)+10) + '01-Jan-2019' + Substring(v,CHARINDEX('Membership',v)+22,14) + '9'
      When CHARINDEX('Section', v) > 0 Then 
           Substring(v,1,CHARINDEX('Section',v)+7) + '01-Jan-2019' + Substring(v,CHARINDEX('Section',v)+19,14) + '9'
      End As m
From #tbl
```

Result:

```
m
Life Membership 01-Jan-2019 to 31-Dec-2019
Oklahoma City Section 01-Jan-2019 to 31-Dec-2019
```

Comment: Sorry you confused `Life Membership 10-Sep-2018 to 31-Dec-2018' 1 row and Oklahoma City Section 10-Sep-2018 to 31-Dec-2018' 2rd row

Comment: James123, Regrets if I am off your mark.  I was wondering if your dataset is such that the ending dates could be different from '31-12-2018' as well as if your first date would be a static change to '01-Jan-2019' as I have demonstrated...  ie: does this script help you?  If not, what is off the mark?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way but to use [replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) twice:

```
declare @fromdate varchar(11) = '10-Sep-2018';
declare @todate varchar(11) = '31-Dec-2018';
declare @newfromdate varchar(11) = '01-Jan-2019';
declare @newtodate varchar(11) = '31-Dec-2019';

create table tablename (id int, description varchar(255));

insert into tablename (id, description) values
(1, 'Life Membership 10-Sep-2018 to 31-Dec-2018'),
(2, 'Oklahoma City Section 10-Sep-2018 to 31-Dec-2018');

update tablename
set description = 
  replace(replace(description, @fromdate, @newfromdate), @todate, @newtodate);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=564c39e258f7bc2fcc3efe70dceb97e1)